# BundleConfig.cs no longer including latest JQuery via {version}

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Current Project:

- ASP.NET 4.5.1
- MVC 5

I recently had to rebuild my entire project from scratch (nuking from orbit, creating new project, and moving over all prior-edited/created files by hand into the new project), but this issue was present even in the old project. So I’m pretty sure it isn’t anything I am doing directly.

The key thing is, I am currently working in Debug mode. Yes, I know, I need to eventually move to Release mode, but I am having problems even when working directly through Visual Studio.

My `jquery-3.0.0.min.js` and `jquery-3.0.0.js` files are exactly where they need to be, and `_reference.js` has them listed as well, however `BundleConfig.cs` can’t seem to find the correct file to include. The only way I can force it to include is by replacing `{version}` with the actual version number. And with updates, this can turn untenable rather quickly.

Suggestions?

---

**EDIT 1:**

My `BundleConfig.cs`, relevant section:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/script.jquery").Include(
  "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js"));
```

My `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/script.jquery")
```

And no, the dot in the name made no difference; I originally had it at the default, but had to change it to keep track of what I was adding.

Comment: Can you post your BundleConfig.cs code? Or at least the snippet where you are including jQuery?

Comment: Done. I have added the snippets.

Comment: Try including the non-minified jQuery. `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/script.jquery").Include(
  "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));` Also, I'm not sure if bundle names can have special characters in them. It's worth a shot and try changing it something like "jquerybundle" and see if that resolves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting a section from a [Post by Rick Anderson](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification):

> Note: Unless EnableOptimizations is true or the debug attribute in the
>   compilation Element  in the Web.config file is set to false, files
>   will not be bundled or minified. Additionally, the .min version of
>   files will not be used,  the full debug versions will be selected.
>   EnableOptimizations  overrides the debug attribute in the compilation
>   Element  in the Web.config file

I tested this and this works as long as you change the dot above to a dash in script.jquery to script-jquery (does not work with the dot separator).

Remember to enable optimizations for debug mode.

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

So the following should work:

`BundleConfig.cs`:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/script-jquery").Include(
"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js"));

//You will need the line below so already minified files can be picked up by the bundler in debug mode.
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

`_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/script-jquery")
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/script.jquery")
```

in head section of the layout.cshtml file.
Also add

```
 @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

this is just a suggestion. I am not sure whether it will work or not.